# pm2 reload/restart with wildcard

Tags: restart, pm2

It's possible to restart a certain group of applications with pm2? Something like `pm2 restart service-*` restarting service-a and service-b? I found `pm2 restart service-a` and `pm2 restart all`, but nothing with wildcard. Of course I could write a shell script, but before I'm interested in the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this, but this works (on Linux anyway). It requires jq and tr.

```
pm2 restart $(pm2 jlist | jq -c '. | map(select(.name | index("service-.") == 0)) | .[] .pm_id' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Basically you're using pm2 jlist to generate a json file of all the processes, jq to filter all the names starting with "service-", then output all the pm_ids, concatenate them and use them for the pm2 restart.